# Grouping imports together from subdirectories

Tags: python, django

Say I have a django app where I'm using folders and subfolders to organize my models:

```
app
    models
        __init__.py
        accounts
            user.py
            profile.py
        social
            facebook.py
            twitter.py
            linkedin.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    urls.py
    views.py
```

My `__init__.py` file is as follows:

```
from .accounts.user import User
from .accounts.profile import Profile

from .social.facebook import Facebook
from .social.twitter import Twitter
from .social.linkedin import LinkedIn
```

Is there any way to group these imports together or make the code shorter?

E.g. (obviously doesn't work)

```
from . import *

# or

from .accounts import *
from .social import *
```

Comment: Not really, a package has no real knowledge of what submodules are under it. The way you already have is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. The package that contains a module will not necessarily know anything about the contents of the module, so in your case `accounts` doesn't know anything about the `User` class in `accounts.user`. There isn't any general way to group things more than what you're already doing.